# I'm trying to get data via axios to send a php server and save as a text file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, vue.js, axios

Hi everyone i want to post data through async and receive it via php
this is my code but it returning empty

```js
async sendMail(email, name) {
  try {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('email', email);
    data.append('name', name);
    return await axios.post(window.MAIL_URL, data);
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error('Unable to connect to server');
  }
},
```

```php
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
echo $_POST['data'];

$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a');
 fwrite($fp,$data);  
 fclose($fp);
```

Comment: You are not sending JSON. Use $_POST directly to access the parameters you are sending.

Comment: `echo $_POST['data1'];` - what sense could that _possibly_ make, when _nothing_ in what you are sending, was named `data1` to begin with?

Comment: `fwrite($fp,$data1);` - `$data1` was also never assigned a value anywhere. This feels like you should really go and stick your nose into some beginner's tutorial at this point.

Comment: @CBroe Hi there I dont have much experience with php and im also getting this error https://snipboard.io/hJrmos.jpg

Comment: @CBroe can you help me write out the php code to handle this call and its also throwing error 'Unable to connect to server'

Comment: These CORS errors are a different and separate issue, but anything but a new one. If you don't know what CORS is, and how to handle things if you want to make a request to a remote URL, then it is time for you to go and read up on the matter first of all now.

Comment: For that you can start with https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to learn what it's all about.

Comment: @CBroe i read about CORS and after doing this https://snipboard.io/oHCMFE.jpg i get error about  header 'request-starttime is not allowed'  i'm a bit confuse

Comment: Looks like your axios request automatically got a header `request-starttime` added to it, probably due to the basic axios setup in the vue environment here. You will need to explicitly allow for that extra request header then, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Comment: look at this https://snipboard.io/YMgqQt.jpg @CBroe

Comment: Confirms my guess then. So either remove that header from there (if you feel confident that you can predict what consequences it might have), or allow for that header in your CORS setup.

Comment: @CBroe thank you with your help i have resolve the issue of cors how do i post the data to my php and get it to save as a text file?

Comment: Like already said at the very start: You stop trying to decode data that is not actually JSON in the first place, and access the POST parameters the _usual way_, using `$_POST`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.